# Try to change values from a function in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, location

I try to catch the Lat and Long data from geolocation.getCurrentLocation, but I cannot save them. It is a function and not return number.
I used lat and lng to save them and get this error. 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of null

Please help me on this.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public constructor( private geo: GeoDataService, private tags: TagService) { }
    title = 'Select a tag:';
    latt =0;
    lngg = 0;
    zoomlv = 18;
    lat = 1;
    lng = 1;

    iconUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_0.png';
    a : Array<any>;
    polylines: Array<any>;
    markers = new Array();
    mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log('Clicked the map at longitude: ' + $event.coords.lng + ', latitude: ' + $event.coords.lat); 
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        }

            var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
          };

          function success(pos) {
            var crd = pos.coords;

            console.log('Your current position is:');
            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
            this.lat = crd.latitude;
            this.lng = crd.longitude;
          }

          function error(err) {
            console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
          }

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public constructor( private geo: GeoDataService, private tags: TagService) { }
    title = 'Select a tag:';
    latt =0;
    lngg = 0;
    zoomlv = 18;
    lat = 1;
    lng = 1;

    iconUrl = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_0.png';
    a : Array<any>;
    polylines: Array<any>;
    markers = new Array();
    mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
        console.log('Clicked the map at longitude: ' + $event.coords.lng + ', latitude: ' + $event.coords.lat); 
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        }

            var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
          };

          let success = (pos) => { <--------- use arrow function 
            var crd = pos.coords;

            console.log('Your current position is:');
            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
            this.lat = crd.latitude;
            this.lng = crd.longitude;
          }

          let error = (err) => { <-------- you can use arrow function here as well 
            console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
          }

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);



    }

}
```

Use arrow function instead of using function expression

In the function expression `this` refers to the object that was created inside the `createObject`. In `the` arrow function case, this refers to `this` of `createObject` itself.

This makes arrow functions useful if you need to access the `this` of the current environment

Answer (score 0):

```
let that = this;
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
  that.lat = crd.latitude;
  that.lng = crd.longitude;
}
```

your mistake was `this`, which reference the current function scope, success function doesn't have `lat` or `lng` that's why